# DataWeave: How to create a date for months or days 1-9 using dw::core::Dates function?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

#### Background

According to [DataWeave documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-dates-functions-date) for the `date(..)` function, a `Date` can be created passing in the `year`, `month`, and `day` parts:

Input:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Dates
output application/json
---
{
   newDate: date({year: 2012, month: 10, day: 11})
}
```

Output:

```
{
   "newDate": "2012-10-11"
}
```

#### My Problem

However, for any `month` or `day` value 1 through 9 I get the following error:

[image: dataweave date error]

It seems that DataWeave is trying to create a date but is not left-padding the numbers with a `0` so that it's ISO8601 `yyyy-MM-dd` compliant.

I tried passing in a left-padded string `01` but I get the following error about the function expecting a number:

[image: dataweave date error]

Comment: This seems to be a bug in date().

Comment: Indeed, this was a bug in version 2.4.0. The fix is available in the latest update for November.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue (`DW-894`) is now resolved per the November 2021 [Mule Runtime release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-4.4.0-release-notes#november-2021):

> Functions in the `Dates` module now accept one-digit numbers for months and days.

Upgrade AnypointStudio to patch release version: 4.4.0-20211026 or later.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I've created a custom function to left pad the values so that they match ISO8601 `yyyy-MM-dd` format. Not ideal, but it works.

```
%dw 2.0

import * from dw::core::Dates
import * from dw::core::Strings

fun toDate(options: {
    year: Number, 
    month: Number, 
    day: Number
}): Date = (
    (
        [
            leftPad(options.year as String, 4, '0'),
            leftPad(options.month as String, 2, '0'),
            leftPad(options.day as String, 2, '0'),
        ] joinBy ('-')
    ) as Date { format: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }
)
```

[image: dataweave playground]